# Can't analyze this function's runtime

Tags: algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, big-o

[image: Click here to check question image]

Hello, I have this question but I got wrong and I just don't understand this.
It is about getting exact runtime of this nested loop.

Specifically, I can understand until "for i=2, inner loop runtime :2n-2". However, after that, I can't understand.

**Question 1)**

First, it says `For i=n, inner loop runtime is n+1`. But this does not make sense from my perspective. Let me assume n=3 and outer loop executes its last loop when i=3, then j will run inner loop for 3 times (from 3 to 5 since j=3=n < 2*n=2*3=6). However, answer says `inner loop runtime is n+1`, if I put 3 into `n+1` it become 4 times. I do not understand why this answer is correct.

**Question 2 )**

How can I get last form of the answer `1.5n^2 + 0.5n` from `2n+(2n-1)+(2n-2)+...+(n+1)`? can you show me overall steps how former become latter in terms of math? Specifically about how `2n + (2n-1) + (2n-2) + ... + (n+1)` become `n*n + (1+2+3+...+n)`? I think formula `n(n+1)/2` is used here with `n=(n+1)` but it doesn't work for me.

Is there any formula used here?

Comment: This is much easier to understand if you write the initial sum as `n + (n+1) + (n+2) + ... + (n+n)`, then it should be pretty obvious how you get to the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1

You are right, for ith inner loop runtime should be **2n-i**, therefore for i=n, inner loop runtime should be n. The answer is wrong.

Question 2

The correct answer should be

> 2n+(2n-1)+...+n

What you can do is you can construct another sum of sequence

> n+(n+1)+...+2n

You match 2n-i with n+i for all i=0..n
Therefore you have (n+1) terms of 3n, so the sum of the 2 exactly same sequence is 3n(n+1) and therefore the sum of 1 sequence is 1.5n(n+1)

Or you can just apply the formula for the sum of Arithmetic progression, please refer to the wiki page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression